# Is there a .NET equivalent syntax to Delphi's Assign/AssignTo?

Tags: c#, .net, variable-assignment

Delphi has a standard mechanism where one object can be copied from another, paraphrased here as:

```
class Persistent 
{
    protected AssignError(Persistent source)
    {
       throw new ConvertError("Cannot assign a {0} to a {1}", source.GetType().Name, this.GetType().Name);
    }

    protected virtual AssignTo(Persistent destination)
    {
        destination.AssignError(this);
    }

    public virtual Assign(Persistent source)
    {
       source.AssignTo(this);
    }
}
```

Does the .NET FCL has a canonical syntax of copying objects between each other?

e.g.:

```
interface IPersistent
{
   public virtual Assign(Object source);
}

public class User : IPersistent
{
    private Image avatarThumbnail;
    private String name;

    public override Assign(Object source)
    {
       if (source is User)
       {
          this.avatarThumbnail = source.avatarThumbnail;
          this.name = source.Name;
       }
       else if (source is Image)
           avatarThumbnail = (Image)source;
       else if (source is DirectoryEntry)
           name = ((DirectoryEntry) source).Firstname + " " + ((DirectoryEntry) source).Lastname;
       else
           throw new AssignError("Assign from {0}", source.GetType());
    }
}
```

Yes i just invented a standard `IPersistent` interface; but is there already a mechanism to copy objects between each other?

**Update**

**Note**: i am talking about the **opposite** of cloning an object.

```
User originalUser = new User();
User theClone = originalUser.Clone();
theClone.Lastname = "Guyer";

originalUser.Assign(theClone);
```

Or, i don't even need to have a clone at all:

```
User u = new User();
u.Assign(salesOrder); //copy name/e-mail from the sales order
```

or

```
SalesOrder s = new SalesOrder();
s.SalesOrderDate = DateTime.Now;
User customer = new Customer("Kirsten");
s.Assign(user); //copy sold-to/ship-to information from the user
```

Comment: are you doing this in VS or using Prism inside Delphi 2010

Comment: It depends - are you expecting these functions to be called automatically when an assignment statement is encountered? (a la C++ copy constructors) - if so, the answer is no.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No, calling `databaseConnection.Assign(font)` would work fine (keeping in mind that i'll be writing the logic that knows how to copy a Font into a DatabaseConnection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET framework has the [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) interface:

> Supports cloning, which creates a new instance of a class with the same value as an existing instance.

And:

> The `ICloneable` interface contains one member, `Clone`, which is intended to support cloning beyond that supplied by `MemberwiseClone`. For more information about cloning, deep versus shallow copies, and examples, see the `Object.MemberwiseClone` method.

---

Update:

As far as I know, there is nothing equivalent to what you want (standard way to copy *some* values between different objects) in the BCL.

Comment: Note that the spec allows `Clone` to be implemented as either a deep copy or a shallow copy.  So, be careful when using an `ICloneable` provided by others.

Comment: Odd that you refer to the `ICloneable` interface, since it is [useless and considered obsolete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/03/125427.aspx). The Framework Design Guidelines advice against anyone using it. It has no advantage over a `Clone` method on an object that doesn't implement `ICloneable`.

Comment: @Steven - The MSDN documentation does not mention that it is obsolete. It is also the closest thing to what the OP is asking for.

Comment: i wasn't referring to cloning an object, since strictly speaking this system allows cloning a `DbConnection` into a `System.Drawing.Font`.

Comment: @Oded: What does the `ICloneable` interface exactly do? It's just an interface; you have to implement cloning yourself and in that case it doesn't add any value over implementing a `Clone` method without that interface. If you advice the OP to use `ICloneable`, you are basically saying 'create a clone method yourself`, which doesn't really help him :-). btw I didn't say `ICloneable` is marked with the `ObsoleteAttribute`, but it is considered to be obsolete, since the Framework Design Guidelines advice against using it.

Comment: @Steven - fair enough. But if you read the comments from the OP, is looks like that's not what he is after, and for what he _does_ want, he is happy to write his own methods.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the standard ICloneable interface, you could perform the copy of public properties/fields using reflection. Here's some code written off the top of my head for doing so:

```
foreach(PropertyInfo mbr in src.GetType().GetProperties())
    mbr.SetValue(dst, src.GetValue(src, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null), BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, null, null)

foreach(FieldInfo mbr in src.GetType().GetFields())
    mbr.SetValue(dst, src.GetValue(src, BindingFlags.GetField, null, null, null), BindingFlags.SetField, null, null, null)
```

Comment: i already have cloning (http://stackoverflow.com/a/78612/12597). The issue now is to copy the clone back into the original.

Comment: How is this any better than using [`MemberwiseClone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) ?

Comment: @Brian - In a lot of ways it isn't. 'MemberwiseClone' is a native implementation of a similar process. The only benefit I've found of implementing it myself is in niche situations where I need control over which fields are copied and to what depth. Not really relevant to the original question here though.